# Node's position in tree as a Feature Vector?

Tags: vector, tree, machine-learning, shortest-path

**Background**
I have a tree of nodes and I'm trying to run some machine learning algorithms to classify them. One of the features I want to use is the position of the nodes in the tree, i.e. closer nodes are likely to be in the same class.

**My Problem**
I'm representing all the features as a vector of numbers. Any thoughts on how I can represent position in the tree as a vector? So that distance b/n two vectors corresponds to distance between nodes in the tree? (I have a small tree of depth around 5-7 and branching around 2-3)

**What I tried**
P.S. I read about algorithms to find shortest distance between 2 nodes (finding each one's distance to their closest common ancestor) One idea I found was to have a vector x where each index corresponds to possible ancestors in the tree. Then set x[i] = numbers of levels from that ancestor. The problem with that is- I don't know what to do with nodes that aren't ancestors.

Answer (score 0):

just put the path of the tree as the vector. then simply calculate the length of the difference between the two paths. so for example.  2,3,1,5,3 is one path. and 2,3,3,5,9,5 is another path. so 2,3 they have in common. so the length of the difference is 1,5,3 and 3,5,9,5 which is 7. good luck

Comment: Thanks, though I was looking for a fixed length vector for the node's position, so I could get something like the distance between two nodes/ vectors x1 and x2 by directly doing x1-x2, but I guess that's too much to hope for :|

Comment: where there's a will, there's a way.

Answer (score 0):

So there is actually a very nice way to derive the features that you want; you can do so with [MDS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling).

What MDS does is that it takes a N by N matrix (here N is number of nodes) where entry a_{i,j} is the distance between item i and item j (node i and node j) and for each item i it will return a D (pre-specified) position vector, D_i, such that the distance between D_i and D_j is approximately a_{i,j}.

Thus, we can have your feature vector with a bit of pre-processing. First, find the shortest distance (in hops) for each pair of nodes (you could use [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm)) then use the distance matrix as input for MDS and specify the number of dimensions for you're position vector, and MDS will output position vectors of said dimensions.

If you search the web I'm sure you can find open sourced implementations to both Floyd-Warshall and MDS.